# Creating a time series

Tags: r

Data starts from `10-03-2016 00:00` and End on `30-03-2016 21:00`.

```
Time Difference of 6 minutes
Time                X
10-03-2016 00:00    396
10-03-2016 00:06    399
10-03-2016 00:12    498
```

Now how to create a time series in R using `ts()`, till month I can create but when it comes to `HMS` I do not know how to handle.

Can someone help me here.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no missing values, then you could use a dummy index for time with 6-minute intervals? That would still allow you to use other `ts` functions like `acf()`. For example,

```
## assumes data are in a data frame called 'df'
## sampling every 6 min = 1/240 day
yy <- ts(df$X, start=1, deltat=1/240)
## make sure 'Time' is OK class for plotting
tt <- strptime(df$Time, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
## you can easily plot the ts
plot(tt, yy, type="l")
```

If there are missing values, or the time index is particularly important to maintain as is, then how about a 'zoo' object from the `zoo` package? For example,

```
library(zoo)
yy <- zoo(df$X, strptime(df$Time, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))
plot(yy)
```